# Problema al llamar un servicio back desde Angular

Tags: java, angular

estoy queriendo llamar al servicio Back desde angular pero al momento de ejecutar la aplicación no llama al servicio.

Cuando ejecuto por el navegador : http://localhost:8080/strategos_rmda/rda-insert/?email=pierro.flores@confianza.pe&module=/com/rma/adm/cmg-capta

si se registra pero desde Angular no me sale ningun error pero veo que tmb no lo llama

**Este es mi codigo servicio Angular**

```
return this.http.get<string[]>(`http://localhost:8080/strategos_rmda/rda-insert/?email=${user}&module=${urls}`)
```

**Este es mi código del Back- JAVA**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/rda-insert", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getInset(@RequestParam(value = "email") String email,@RequestParam(value = "module") String module){
        SpResultSetRunner r1=spResultSetManager.createRunner();
        System.out.println("entro");
        r1.setDb("storage_lake");
        r1.setSchm("com.act");
        r1.setSp("SPREGISTRAR");
        r1.setParam(1,email);
        r1.setParam(2,module);
        Object[] list = new Object[]{};
        System.out.println(email);
        System.out.println(module);

        list = r1.getResultAsList().toArray(list);
        GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
        String data = gson.create().toJson(list);
        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Angular las peticiones HTTP devuelven un Observable. Y los observables no se ejecutan hasta que no se haya suscrito un observador.

```
this.http.get<string[]>(`url`)
.subscribe(r => {}) // se suscribe un observador y la petición se realiza
```